# Regex that matches only when whole pattern is found

Tags: php, regex

I have this text:

> arnaldo felix toro calzadilla tomo 133 l 002353 p 119 numero 119

and using this regex: `t[^\s]{0,4} (\d*)\s*` to find the string `tomo 133`, that matches the whole pattern.

Instead I'm getting 2 matches:

- `toro` and
- `tomo 133`

I want to match only the second one.

As you can see is not multiline, anchor or case-sensitive problem. Anchors don't solve the problem 'cause i'm not dealing with whole lines inputs.

I'm using PHP7, using `preg_match_all()`, but `preg_match()` don't make a difference.

Save the expression here in case you want to play with it https://regex101.com/r/aRxqvI/1.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Make the numbers not optional. `\d+`

Comment: What's the underlying criteria for your regular expression?

Comment: Nothing can be done until you decide what is the difference between `toro` and `tomo 133`.

Comment: The comment of @chris85 did it for me, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\d*` matches a digit character `0` or more times (so optional) because of the `*`.  You want `+` for `1` or more times: `\d+`

Comment: Thanks @AbraCadaver, your answer solves it, didn't quite get it at first, but chris85 comment above helped me. Thanks